# shell awk script to remove duplicate lines

Tags: awk

I am trying to remove duplicate lines from a file including the original ones but the following command that I am trying is sorting the lines and I want them to be in the same order as they are in input file.

```
awk '{++a[$0]}END{for(i in a) if (a[i]==1) print i}' test.txt
```

```
Input:
123
aaa
456
123
aaa
888
bbb

Output I want:
456
888
bbb
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this in `awk` only then could you please try following; if not worried about order.

```
awk '{a[$0]++};END{for(i in a){if(a[i]==1){print i}}}' Input_file
```

---

---

To get the unique values in same order in which they occur in Input_file try following.

```
awk '
!a[$0]++{
  b[++count]=$0
}
{
  c[$0]++
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    if(c[b[i]]==1){
      print b[i]
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
456
888
bbb
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                        ##Starting awk program from here.
!a[$0]++{                    ##Checking condition if current line is NOT occur in array a with more than 1 occurrence then do following.
  b[++count]=$0              ##Creating an array b with index count whose value is increasing with 1 and its value is current line value.
}
{
  c[$0]++                    ##Creating an array c whose index is current line and its value is occurrence of current lines.
}
END{                         ##Starting END block for this awk program here.
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){     ##Starting for loop from here.
    if(c[b[i]]==1){          ##Checking condition if value of array c with index is value of array b with index i equals to 1 then do following.
      print b[i]             ##Printing value of array b.
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file                ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 5):

Simpler code if you are okay with reading input file twice:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++; next} a[$0]==1' ip.txt ip.txt
456
888
bbb
```

With single pass:

```
$ awk '{a[NR]=$0; b[$0]++} END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) if(b[a[i]]==1) print a[i]}' ip.txt
456
888
bbb
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the input is piped to the `awk` script, or the input comes from a terminal, or some other device that cannot be opened twice to get the same data.  That isn't automatically a reason to reject it, but it is a (major?) limitation.

Comment: yeah good point, in those cases, will have to  read it only once..

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ b[$0]++; a[n++]=$0; }END{ for (i in a){ if(b[a[i]]==1) print a[i] }}' input
```

Lines are added to array `b`, the order of lines is kept in array `a`.
If, in the end, the count is `1`, the line is printed.

Sorry, i misread the question at first, and i corrected the answer, to be almost the same as @Sundeep ...